# Please correct and re-submit. An App ID with Identifier 'com.brs.paysrc' (example) is not available. Please enter a different string

Tags: ios, iphone, app-id, itunes-app

I have an existing app with bundle identifier com.brs.paysrc example and the app is live on store. It was created using a wildcard app id. Now i want to enable push notifications for this app. So i tried to create a new app id with b uncle identifier as com.brs.paysrc but it give some an error saying There were errors in the data supplied. Please correct and re-submit. An App ID with Identifier 'com.brs.paysrc' (example) is not available. Please enter a different string.

Answer (score 3):

(I'm not sure if this'll help you...)

I had the same issue with an app our company has in the App Store.

The reason was because we have both a Developer Program (so we're allowed to submit an App onto the App Store) and an Enterprise Program  (so I can make in-house copies of the app).

Our Bundle ID was registered under the Developer Program, but I had logged into the Apple Developer website and had chosen the Enterprise Program group.

In the Apple Developers website, the **Identifies\App IDs** didn't show our Bundle ID, because it was actually registered under our Developer Program... but, of course, it still refused to let me create the Bundle ID a second time, and, as usual, the error message gave no clue as to what the problem was.

I really hate the whole Certificates/Provisioning Profile stuff with Apple.  Their error handling/reporting, when you get something wrong, is a farce.  And it'll happily let you create non-working apps, deploy them to a device, then report a "Your app could not be installed *at this time*" when things go wrong.

Even yesterday, when I was ready to deploy a new version of the App to the App Store, I could create an Archive, the Validate said it was all fine, but then when I submitted it, it reported 3 errors in my .plist file.

Oh, and remember that your Bundle ID is stored in the .plist file and in the settings:

[image]

Make sure this Bundle ID is correct in both places!

(Sigh.)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Bundle ID stored in the .plist file and in the settings: both are same. We just don't want to create one more Bundle ID for existing app, Just enable push notification for existing app and bundle ID.

Comment: My issues is solved. Someone from our team has registered this bundle ID using free provisioning. We have requested for app store support team to know why couldn't able to add.

Answer (score 0):

You might have clicked it twice (I did).  Check here, to see if your id is there: https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Please give unique bundle ID**, it will resolve your problem. Sometimes the same bundle ID is already used by another app. Hence this issue occurs. Try with different bundle ID it will resolve your problem.